# Rspec test case logic for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math, model, rspec

this is my model 'Order' and the 'Order_item' model has association with it

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :order_items
    belongs_to :user

    before_save :set_subtotal

    def subtotal
      order_items.collect { |order_item| order_item.valid? ? order_item.unit_price * order_item.quantity : 0 }.sum
    end
  
    private
  
    def set_subtotal
      self[:subtotal] = subtotal
    end
end
```

2nd model:

```
class OrderItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :order
  
  before_save :set_unit_price
  before_save :set_total
  
  def unit_price
    # If there is a record
  if persisted? 
      self[:unit_price]
    else
      product.price
    end
  end

  def total
   return unit_price * quantity
  end

  private

  def set_unit_price
    self[:unit_price] = unit_price
  end

  def set_total
    self[:total] = total * quantity
  end
end
```

i am trying to check the test case of RSPEC for the 'SUbtotal' function but i can't seem to find the logic

Rspec model file:  Order

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Order, type: :model do
  let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user) }
  let(:subtotal) { FactoryBot.create(:order, subtotal: 1000) }
  let(:items) { FactoryBot.create(:order_item)  }

  describe 'callbacks' do
    it { is_expected.to callback(:set_subtotal).before(:save) }
  end

  describe 'associations' do
    it { is_expected.to belong_to(:user) }
    it { is_expected.to have_many(:order_items) }
  end

  #Gives Error i dont know how to get this

  # describe 'subtotal' do
  #   it 'it should calculate the subtotal' do
  #     expect(Order.subtotal).to eq(1000)
  #   end
  # end
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to call an instance method on the class. If you change to call subtotal on an instance you'll see a different error.

```
Order.new.subtotal
```

should have that defined.

To get your call to work in the spec you would need the method defined on the class with `self`.

```
def self.subtotal
...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @nikkypx already said you're calling an instance method on the class itself.

In your test setup you created an instance of Order named `subtotal`.
So to make it work you'd have to change your test to:

```
expect(subtotal.subtotal).to eq(1000)
```

Now since you named your instances funky it sounds confusing. More logical would be to name the Order instance `order`.

```
let(:order) { FactoryBot.create(:order, subtotal: 1000) }
```